# Why "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method" from (JNIenv*)->GetStaticMethodID?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, jnienv

My Android NDK project's Java Code calls C++ function ,

```
    extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_crimson_tub_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env, jobject jo)
```

I want to call

```
    public static void requestPermissions(@NonNull final Activity activity, @NonNull final String[] permissions, @IntRange(from = 0L) final int requestCode)
```

found in Android Document:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity, java.lang.String[], int)

I have tried few variations of the code where i think the problem is,

```
jmethodID jmid = env->GetStaticMethodID(clzz,"requestPermissions", "(Landroid/app/Activity;[Ljava/lang/String;I)V;"),
//jmethodID jmid = env->GetStaticMethodID(clzz,"requestPermissions", "(Lcom/company/project/MainActivity;[Ljava/lang/String;I)V;"),
  //jmethodID jmid = env->GetStaticMethodID(clzz,"requestPermissions", "(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/String;I)V;"),
```

all of the above alternatives lead to same exception,

```
    No pending exception expected: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static method "Landroid/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat;.requestPermissions(Landroid/app/Activity;[Ljava/lang/String;I)V;"
```

c++ code,

```
    extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
    Java_com_crimson_tub_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv *env,jobject jo) {

        std::string hello;

        jobjectArray ret;
        int i;

        char *data[2]= { "android.permission.CAMERA" ,
                 "android.permission-group.CALENDAR"};

        ret= (jobjectArray)env->NewObjectArray(2,env->FindClass("java/lang/String"),env->NewStringUTF(""));

        for(i=0;i<2;i++) env->SetObjectArrayElement(ret,i,env->NewStringUTF(data[i]));

        jint result = 0xffffffff;

        jclass clzz = env->FindClass("android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat");
        if (!clzz){
            hello += "-class";
        }else{
            hello += "+class";
        }

        jmethodID jmid = env->GetStaticMethodID(clzz,"requestPermissions", "(Landroid/app/Activity;[Ljava/lang/String;I)V;"),
        //jmethodID jmid = env->GetStaticMethodID(clzz,"requestPermissions", "(Lcom/company/project/MainActivity;[Ljava/lang/String;I)V;"),
          //jmethodID jmid = env->GetStaticMethodID(clzz,"requestPermissions", "(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/String;I)V;"),

        env->CallStaticVoidMethod(clzz,jmid,jo,ret,result);

        env->DeleteGlobalRef(jo);
        return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());

    }
```

i would like to be able to call Android Java functions via JNI like,

```
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions
```

directly from c++ so later i can remove Java code from my project.

I have been working on this issue for quite a while now and still unsuccessful.

Gratitude towards All the help and it is greatly appreciated.

Thank you all.

Comment: Since when is `Activity` equivalent to `java.lang.Object` in a method signature? Your method signature is wrong. Don't guess at this. Get it from `javap -s`. It is never wrong.

Comment: @user207421 that means the first commented line. which also returns 

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with 

(Landroid/app/Activity;[Ljava/lang/String;I)V;"

Comment: discovery: javap cannot find "android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat"
in android.jar. im using SDK 28. i think this is related, and the failure is at FindClass(). but it returns not null. any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: You're supposed to use slashes in the name you pass to `FindClass`, not dots.

Comment: fixed it. but the same result

Comment: If `FndClass()` fails, or indeed any other JNI call, you should print the exception, and when you get any exception you should not proceed as though it hadn't happened. What we need now is the `FindClass()` exception. Poor quality code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was the ; after the V in the signature. now it works. Lol.

Answer (score 0):

With I, J and V in the signature, we dont use ; after these.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34804755)